# Looking for help: How do I create a plot like below?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot like below. Especially, How do I custermize the `x` axis following the example figure?

[image]

I used the code below and got a different plot. Raw data can be found in the code chunck.

```
pplotcoef1 <- ggplot(plotcoef1, aes(x=rowname, y=Estimate, fill = Season)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('FFrez','0-18','18-23','>23',
                              'WFrez','0-10','10-19','>19',
                              'SFrez','0-25','25-31','>25')) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=`2.5 %`, ymax=`97.5 %`), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.1, 0.8)) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10))


# below is the raw data

structure(list(rowname = c("FFrez", "0-18", "18-23", ">23", "WFrez", 
"0-10", "10-19", ">19", "SFrez", "0-25", "25-31", ">25"), Estimate = c(-0.0012003609086715, 
-0.00224572693825549, 0.0317249635237625, -0.0309580812988414, 
0.0055434323683689, 0.0100720094187078, -0.0426109330603611, 
0.767362840735131, -0.119914397214232, -0.0027280282076923, 0.0118992891275962, 
-0.038882023304552), `2.5 %` = c(-0.0144483912522908, -0.00394322882833284, 
0.0210026254674657, -0.0424119567821081, -3.41088614867324e-05, 
0.00540180608554072, -0.0582083846824812, 0.569529275981415, 
-0.159785447309533, -0.00451436995685489, 0.00263298667404979, 
-0.0533405234131965), `97.5 %` = c(0.0120476694349478, -0.00054822504817814, 
0.0424473015800594, -0.0195042058155746, 0.0111209735982245, 
0.0147422127518749, -0.027013481438241, 0.965196405488847, -0.0800433471189307, 
-0.00094168645852972, 0.0211655915811427, -0.0244235231959076
), Season = c("Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Fall", "Winter", "Winter", 
"Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring")), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Forgot to provide the source of the example figure. It was obtained from the paper by [Tack et al. (2015)](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2015/05/06/1415181112).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also this approach with facets that emulate a plot as the one you shared:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
plotcoef1 %>%
  mutate(rowname=factor(rowname,levels = c('FFrez','0-18','18-23','>23',
                                           'WFrez','0-10','10-19','>19',
                                           'SFrez','0-25','25-31','>25'),
                        ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=rowname, y=Estimate,group=Season,fill=Season)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=`2.5 %`, ymax=`97.5 %`), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('blue','yellow','red'))+
  facet_wrap(.~Season,scales='free_x',drop = T,strip.position = 'bottom')+
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold',size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color='black',face='bold',size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color='black',face='bold',size = 10),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        plot.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold',hjust=0.5))+
  ggtitle('My title')
```

Output:

[image]

In order to have the desired order in facets, try this:

```
#Code 2
plotcoef1 %>%
  mutate(rowname=factor(rowname,levels = c('FFrez','0-18','18-23','>23',
                                           'WFrez','0-10','10-19','>19',
                                           'SFrez','0-25','25-31','>25'),
                        ordered = T)) %>%
  mutate(Season=factor(Season,levels = unique(Season),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=rowname, y=Estimate,group=Season,fill=Season)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=`2.5 %`, ymax=`97.5 %`), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('blue','yellow','red'))+
  facet_wrap(.~Season,scales='free_x',drop = T,strip.position = 'bottom')+
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'top',
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold',size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color='black',face='bold',size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color='black',face='bold',size = 10),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "points"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        strip.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        plot.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold',hjust=0.5))+
  ggtitle('My title')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This approach solves the problem. I have several follow-up questions.

Comment: @YabinDa Sure tell me!

Comment: This approach solves the problem. I have several follow-up questions. The first is which parameter determines the space between groups and which parameter determines the space within the group? For the former space, I tried modity the `panel.spacing`, and it worked however divided the `x` axis into several segments. The second question is the order of the season should be Fall followed by Winter followed by Spring as specified in the `mutate` function. However the output gave us a different order.

Comment: @YabinDa I will adjust the order. For the space you can check `panel.spacing` just give me a second!

Comment: Thanks. I changed your original setting `panel.spacing = unit(0, "points")` to `panel.spacing = unit(3, "points")`. It did increase the space between groups, however, it also created gaps on `x` axis.

Comment: @YabinDa I have added an update for the order of facets. I hope that can be useful for you. For spacing play around the units to obtain the desired measures.

Comment: I got confused. Which part in the code did you change to get the desired order? I cannot figure it out.....

Comment: @YabinDa I have updated the second code. Sorry I added the same code. You have to format seasons as ordered factor. I hope that is clear now!

Comment: Yes. Problem solved with the factorized season. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If okay for you, you could use `facets`. To order the bars within the plot you have to set factors first. And also I deleted `fill`

```
plotcoef1$rowname = factor(
  plotcoef1$rowname,
  c(
    'FFrez',
    '0-18',
    '18-23',
    '>23',
    'WFrez',
    '0-10',
    '10-19',
    '>19',
    'SFrez',
    '0-25',
    '25-31',
    '>25'
  )
)
ggplot(plotcoef1, aes(x = rowname, y = Estimate)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+ 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=`2.5 %`, ymax=`97.5 %`), width=.2,
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  theme_classic() +
  facet_grid(. ~ Season, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]